# Why does Nuitka hinted compilation return error?

Tags: python-3.x, nuitka

```
File "hinted-mods.py", line 275, in __init__ options.recurse_modules.append(f) AttributeError: 'Values' object has no attribute 'recurse_modules'
```

I get this error when I do `python nuitka-hints.py main.py` in console

I used the hinted compilation from nuitka utilities found here :
https://github.com/Nuitka/NUITKA-Utilities/tree/master/hinted-compilation

Answer (score 2):

nuitka options no longer has the "recurse_modules" attribute. it was replaced by "follow_modules".
In my case, I simply modified the code(in hinted-mods.py, replace all "recures_modules" to "follow_modules"), and it worked.
check this PR https://github.com/Nuitka/NUITKA-Utilities/pull/63